# scrapy's sitemapcrawler processing links before crawl

Tags: scrapy

Is it possible to use rules with the sitemapcrawler? There are some sites that have old sitemaps with http links instead of https. Every time I crawl them, all links are redirected (301) which will create useless traffic on their (and my) side. I thought the easiest solution is to process the links before they get crawled and change the scheme from http to https.

Can I do it with rules or should i just use the default middleware and just let it parse all urls basically twice? Ignoring the redirect could be a solution but I find it "dirtier".

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy sitemapcrawler have attribute for rules.

See:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.SitemapSpider.sitemap_rules

You can add regexp which will filter non https urls.

Comment: actually i'm not sure rules are what i need. I think they are applied after having downloaded the page, which is not what i need.

Comment: I have case where crawled website sitemap includes other sitemaps. I'm using "sitemap_follow" regexp to define which sitemaps urls should be followed combined with "sitemap_rules" regexp to specify which links only. Running crawler works as expected, my crawler is only going after specified urls, which contains targeted data by me.

Comment: are you sure that the sitemap_rules are applied before crawling ? I thought you can only discard the one you don't want and not really do what i expect. I should experiment maybe

Comment: Ok, after checking more documentation and implementation of SitemapSpider I see only 2 solutions. You can use XMLFeedSpider and parse on your own sitemap or override function _parse_sitemap(self, response) and process yielded Response objects and change from http to https see my another answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override _parse_sitemap of SitemapSpider, check it implementation in SitemapSpider, example below:

```
def _parse_sitemap(self, response):
    sitemap_generator = super(MySitemapSpider, self)._parse_sitemap(response)
    if sitemap_generator is None:
        return

    for response_url in sitemap_generator:
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        # do something with the URL
        yield response_url
```